# Skype 4.2 won't launch on Lenovo y510p Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype

I try and install skype 4.2 from the Synaptic package center and it says installed but when i try to run it nothing happens.  I've tried both the Skype:i386 and the regular Skype with the binary files installed.  I tried reinstalling, installing through terminal, installing through software center, and it just never runs.

Output below is from when i ran `dpkg -l skype`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  skype          4.2.0.11-0ub i386         client for Skype VOIP and instant
```

Comment: What happened when you just run `skype`?

Comment: nothing...when i put the icon in the launcher and open from there it blinks like other applications do before they open and it then it just stops...then i go check the processes and skype isn't running

Comment: What error message do you get if you run `skype` from a terminal window?

Comment: If I type Skype into the Terminal I get this reply:

skype: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Skype from a terminal window with this command:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 skype
```

and let us know what happened.

*Edit:*

Since it worked, this is one way to fix the start of Skype more persistently:

- Create a file named `~/bin/skype`
- Give it this content:

  `#!/bin/sh
  exec env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/bin/skype "$@"`
- Make it executable using `chmod +x ~/bin/skype`
- Log out and log in again

Comment: It worked and logged in fine finally, but I can still only run skype using that command. Is there a way to fix that now?

Comment: @user307105: Yes, see my edited answer.

Comment: I created a file in both /usr/bin and /bin named Skype, put that content then saved it; then ran the chmod +x command on terminal. i then logged out and back in and tried again and now when i run skype from terminal it says directory not found, even though i know its there.
and when i run the preload command it now gives me ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.

Comment: @user307105: That's not good. I meant that you should create it in your home directory, i.e. `/home/[yourname]/bin/skype`. I suggest you do so, remove the file from /bin and reinstall skype (if you created a text file as /usr/bin/skype, you overwrote the actual skype program...).